# How to generate a unique 8 digit number using crypto in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, cryptojs

I want to generate a unique number everytime. I have used crypto module for that.

```
const alphanu = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')
```

This will generate alphanumeric string of length 32. I want to generate a number of length 8.

I tried randomInt as well.

```
const num = crypto.randomInt(10000000,99999999)
```

Will it always generate a unique number?

How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: You can't randomly create unique numbers without storing which numbers are already created. Why can't you simply start with 0 and increment? You could add a timestamp or a counter.

Comment: "Will it always generate a unique number?" No

Comment: @ThomasSablik I wanted to bypass some checks for certain users, that's the reason why I was creating 8 digit number.

Comment: Start with 10000000 and increment. Why do you need a random number?

Comment: @ThomasSablik if I stop and run the program, there is no way the incremented number is remembered. I would have to make a database call to get to know the number and this makes it complicated but if I dont find any other solution, then I will follow this method.

Comment: You could use the Unix timestamp - 2100000000. This will generate unique increasing numbers and you don't have to remember created numbers.

Comment: *Will it always generate a unique number?* How can it, since there are only 99999999-10000000=89999999 possibilities? How many *unique* numbers do you need?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I'll need a few hundreds.

Answer (score 3):

Your "unique" requirement will be harder to achieve than you think. If you meant "non-deterministic", then just use `crypto.randomInt()` as you did in your question:

```
crypto.randomInt(10**7, 10**8-1) // 8 digit, no leading zeroes
crypto.randomInt(0, 10**8-1).toString().padStart(8, "0") // 8 digits, allows leading zeroes
```

Technically speaking, this is [psuedorandom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), not random. However, for most use cases, you won't be able to tell the difference.

Now if you need unique, then here's two fairly easy approaches you could use:

1. Store every number you've already used in a database, or
2. Start at 0 and increment by one each time and add leading zeroes if necessary (or start at 10^7 if you don't want leading zeroes). With this, all you need to do is store the last number used. However, with this approach, the result is deterministic, which might be a security drawback depending on your use case.

Comment: @ThomasSablik What is your proposed third option? AFAIK there's no way to both keep the result non-deterministic and assure uniqueness.

Comment: Use a timestamp. Use a timestamp with random. Use a counter with random.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ok, fine I've removed the part suggesting those are the only two possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

To make a random and unique number, you're going to have to mix `.random()` and a time stamp together.

Here's a simple UID generator I've been using for a while now, I've modified the `.substring()` so that it returns 8 characters.

```js
const alphanu = Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(13);

console.log(alphanu);
```

Comment: I will try this. I had not thought of using date. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For guaranteed unique numbers you are right to use encryption. Because encryption is one-to-one then unique inputs guarantee unique outputs. Just encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, ... with the same key (and IV if used) and you will get unique numbers out.

You want 8 digit numbers, so the output range is 0 .. 99,999,999. That is a 27 bit number. You could use a 32 bit encryption (which gives 10 digits) with [cycle walking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption#FPE_from_cycle_walking) to get numbers within range. If the cycle walking takes too long, then you could either accept a 10 digit output or write a simple 28-bit [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) with four or six rounds. That will not be cryptographically secure, but will give you enough pseudo-randomness with guaranteed uniqueness.

Comment: I got to know two new methods now, will try and see which is faster and which suits my case. Thank you!